# Spring Integration: Send response to client http inbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a http inbound gateway which needs to  receive the request validate it and then immediately send response to client. After the response is sent back, my SI flow needs to continue with further processing. The response should be sent to client as soon as the validation is complete.  Sending of response shouldn't wait  until my entire processing is complete. How can I trigger SI flow to continue with further processing once the response is sent. What is the appropriate SI component for this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the response is a simply `200 OK`, use an inbound channel adapter (not a gateway) and make the first channel after the validation an `ExecutorChannel`. Then, immediately the message is handed off to the executor, the response will be sent.

If you need a custom reply, use a gateway and make the first channel after the validation a publish-subscribe channel (with an executor), construct the reply in one consumer of that channel, process the request in another.